# Reading text files with system variables by batch script?

Tags: cmd, batch-file

I have a text file param.txt which looks like following:

```
"SaveOnExit","true"
"tmp_dir","%tmp%\app"
"GUID","ab0809eda345febca"
```

I want to read this file by batch (Win7) and echo it to a new file with "translated" system variables, e.g.

```
"SaveOnExit","true"
"tmp_dir","C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\app"
"GUID","ab0809eda345febca"code here
```

I've seen samples for parsing like

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%G IN (param.txt) DO @echo %%G
```

Unfortunately is not transforming the system variable %temp%.
Output remains the same as the original file.
I played around with SETLOCAL EnableExtensions and EnableDelayedExpansion without any results.
As the request is to keep as simple as possible usage of VBS, Powershell or additional tools is no option.

Is there any way to get the output as requested?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("inputfile.txt") do (
        call echo(%%a
    )) > outputfile.txt
```

To expand the variable reference inside the readed line you need to force the parser to process the content of the variable. You can use the `call` command to force a an aditional parse on the line to get the variable expanded.